# Exampl: If the given Input String is HelloWorld the length of the String must be displayed as 10

Tags: groovy

Write a groovy program to find the length of the given string.
The goal of the program is to make you familiar with strings in groovy.

Exampl: If the given Input String is HelloWorld the length of the String must be displayed as 10.

Sample Input For Custom Testing
HelloWorld

Sample Output
10

class HelloGroovy{static void main(String[] args){//your code hereprintln(“Hello, World”);}}

Comment: I assume this is homework of some sort. Stackoverflow isn't for completing homework for you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a verbatim homework assignment